# Enumerating path variations

Tags: graphs, enumeration, eulerian-paths

I have a graph and I'm trying to enumerate all paths that start at node $S$, end at node $E$, uses each edge, and minimizes the number of edges used (i.e. it can only re-use an edge if strictly necessary).

What I am wondering is that if I have a solution path, e.g. $SADBCABE$, can I find all other valid paths that use the same set of edges by iterating over the ways in which I can reverse loops?

In other words, the example path has two loops: one that over $A$ ($ADBCA$), and one over $B$ ($BCAB$). This leads to five possible paths that can be made by reversing these paths that can be named: $A_0B_0$, $A_0B_1$, $A_1B_0$, $A_1B_1$, and $B_1A_1$. Here, $B_1A_1$ refers to reversing path $B$ and then reversing path $A$. This example makes it clear that order matters.

Will this method of enumeration miss any paths containing the same edge set?

---

**EDIT:** After some discussion in the comments, it is clear that further reversals on the five paths listed above could produce previously unfound paths.  It seems like to use this methodology, I would also have to keep a fringe set and ensure that all reversals on the fringe produce paths that I've already found before removing it. This would no longer be a simple enumeration of permutations, but rather a BFS, which is unfortunately less deterministic. Is this already a known problem that I could read more about? I've tried Googling various things about domino trains (since each edge could be thought of as a domino), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: In $SABCDAFCGAE$, there are just two "ordered simple cycles", $ABCDA$ and $AFCGA$, and I don't think they can be interleaved into, e.g., $SABCGAFCDAE$.  Whether this is a counterexample depends on what you mean by "cycle" -- while the two I gave above are the only simple cycles *produced as you walk along the given path*, they are not the only cycles if you consider the *set* (without order) of edges contained in the path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The path you listed **can** be found eventually. Note that $CDAFC$ is also a cycle, and by repeatedly reversing the three $A$ cycles and the one $C$ cycle, that path can be constructed. I wrote a Python script to randomly reverse cycles until your's was found, the shortest sequence I found was: $SABCFADCGAE$, $SABCFAGCDAE$, $SAFCBAGCDAE$, $SABCFAGCDAE$, $SABCGAFCDAE$.

Comment: @j_random_hacker However, this does bring to light one important thing: further reversals on the five paths originally listed can produce new paths, so thank you for that. It seems like to use this methodology, I would also have to keep a fringe set and ensure that all reversals on the fringe produce paths that I've already found before removing it. This would no longer be a simple enumeration of permutations, but rather a BFS, which is unfortunately less deterministic.

Comment: The problem of finding such a path is called the [Chinese Postman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem).